# Error retrieving data from Api Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Api and Xamarin forms client using Visual Studio 2017.

I'm getting an error

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Invalid JSON string

because `response.Content` is null,  when retrieving data from API but when paste this Url in browser "https://localhost:44305/api/Agreement/GetAgreementText/1" it shows data in the browser. When I run using client it's not hit to api method debug point .

Here is my APi method

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetAgreementText/{id}")]
public DefaultApiResult GetAgreementText(long Id)
{
    Company com = _companyRepository.Get(Id);
    string st = com.AgreementText;

    DefaultApiResult result = new DefaultApiResult
            {
                Data = st
            };
    return result;
}
```

Here is my client application Api invoking method

```
public string GetAgreementTextLoading(long idCompany)
{
    string agreementText = "";
    // var token = _tokenService.GetLastActivateToken().Hash;
    var clientURL = "https://localhost:44305/";
    var client = new RestClient(clientURL);
    var request = new RestRequest("api/Agreement/GetAgreementText/{Id}", Method.GET);

    request.AddUrlSegment("Id", idCompany.ToString());

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    AppRestResponse apiResponse = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<AppRestResponse>(response.Content);

    var statusMessage = "";

    if (apiResponse.Success)
    {
        statusMessage = "Success.";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Content))
        {
            agreementText = apiResponse.Data.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid response");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        agreementText = "Error retrieving agreement text";
    }

    return agreementText;
}

public class AppRestResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AppRestReponseError> ErrorMessages { get; set; }
}

public class DefaultApiResult
{
        public bool Success
        {
            get
            {
                return ErrorMessages.Count == 0;
            }
            private set { }
        }

        public List<ErrorMessage> ErrorMessages { get; set; }

        public object Data { get; set; }

        public DefaultApiResult()
        {
            ErrorMessages = new List<ErrorMessage>();
        }

        public DefaultApiResult(string errorMessage)
            :this()
        {
            ErrorMessages.Add(new ErrorMessage()
            {
                Message = errorMessage
            });
        }

        public DefaultApiResult(string[] errorMessages)
            :this()
        {
            foreach (var errorMessage in errorMessages)
            {
                ErrorMessages.Add(new ErrorMessage()
                {
                    Message = errorMessage
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please post the definitions of `DefaultApiResult` and `AppRestResponse`?

Comment: I added it to my queshtion

Comment: Are you sure you are running both projects at same time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `SimpleJson` and the rest client you are using .

However , assuming you're using the `RestSharp` , it seems that there's no need to use the SimpleJson to deserialize response here .

I just remove the following codes  :

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
AppRestResponse apiResponse = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<AppRestResponse>(response.Content);
```

and add the following two lines:

```
IRestResponse<AppRestResponse> response = client.Execute<AppRestResponse>(request);
var apiResponse= response.Data;
```

It works as expected .

Comment: I checked your code "System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure" error is there

Comment: @charitht99perera Could you please provide more information about the error of `System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure` ?